# RSocket Java Spring @AuthenticationPrincipal with JWT

Tags: spring-security, jwt, rsocket, rsocket-java

How can we use @AuthenticationPrincipal with a RSocket Method @AuthenticationPrincipal Mono token

```
    public Mono<String> uppercase(String s, @AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<JwtAuthenticationToken> token) { 
        //Token is always null 
        return Mono.just(s.toUpperCase());
    }
```

I created a RSocketSecurityConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRSocketSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Slf4j
public class RSocketSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;

    @Bean
    PayloadSocketAcceptorInterceptor rsocketInterceptor(RSocketSecurity rsocket) {
        rsocket
                .authorizePayload(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                )
                .jwt(jwtSpec -> {
                    jwtSpec.authenticationManager(jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(reactiveJwtDecoder()));
                });
        return rsocket.build();
    }
   @Bean
ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() {

    NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder decoder = (NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder)
            ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
    return decoder;
}

   @Bean
    public JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder) {
        JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager = new JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(reactiveJwtDecoder);

        JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager.setJwtAuthenticationConverter( new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(authenticationConverter));

        return jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager;
    }
@Bean
RSocketMessageHandler messageHandler(RSocketStrategies strategies) {
    RSocketMessageHandler mh = new RSocketMessageHandler();
    mh.getArgumentResolverConfigurer().addCustomResolver(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    mh.setRSocketStrategies(strategies);

    return mh;
}
```

Full UpperCaseController:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class UpperCaseController {

    @MessageMapping("uppercase")
    public Mono<String> uppercase(String s, @AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<JwtAuthenticationToken> token) {
        JwtAuthenticationToken currentToken = token.block();
        if ( currentToken == null ) {
            log.info("token is null");
        }
        return Mono.just(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Full ConnectController:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class ConnectController {

    @ConnectMapping("connect")
    void connectShellClientAndAskForTelemetry(RSocketRequester requester,
                                              @Payload String client) {

        requester.rsocket()
                .onClose()
                .doFirst(() -> {
                    // Add all new clients to a client list
                    log.info("Client: {} CONNECTED.", client);
                })
                .doOnError(error -> {
                    // Warn when channels are closed by clients
                    log.warn("Channel to client {} CLOSED", client);
                })
                .doFinally(consumer -> {
                    // Remove disconnected clients from the client list

                    log.info("Client {} DISCONNECTED", client);
                })
                .subscribe();
    }
}
```

RSocket Client:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RSocketClient {

    private static final MimeType SIMPLE_AUTH = MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.getString());
    MimeType BEARER_AUTH =
            MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.getString());

    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN = "....";
    private final RSocketRequester requester;
    private RSocketStrategies rsocketStrategies;

    public RSocketClient(RSocketRequester.Builder requesterBuilder,
                         @Qualifier("rSocketStrategies") RSocketStrategies strategies) {
        this.rsocketStrategies = strategies;
        SocketAcceptor responder = RSocketMessageHandler.responder(rsocketStrategies, new RSocketClientHandler());
            requester = requesterBuilder
                .setupRoute("connect")
                .setupData("MyTestClient")
                                .setupMetadata(new BearerTokenMetadata(BEARER_TOKEN), BEARER_AUTH)
                .rsocketStrategies(builder ->
                        builder.encoder(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEncoder()))
                .rsocketConnector(connector -> connector.acceptor(responder))
                .connectTcp("localhost", 7000)
                .block();

        requester.rsocket()
                .onClose()
                .doOnError(error -> log.warn("Connection CLOSED"))
                .doFinally(consumer -> log.info("Client DISCONNECTED"))
                .subscribe();
    }
    public void uppercase() {
               String response = requester
                .route("uppercase")
                .metadata(BEARER_TOKEN, BEARER_AUTH)
                .data("Hello")
                .retrieveMono(String.class).block();
        log.info(response);
    }
}
```

I have done something very similar for Spring REST and it works fine but for RSocket the token is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have started with https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/17/getting-started-with-rsocket-spring-security

I was able to get this working for my codebase using a different type than @Payload

```
  @ConnectMapping
  fun handle(requester: RSocketRequester, @AuthenticationPrincipal jwt: String) {
    logger.debug("connected $jwt")
  }
```

```
  @MessageMapping("runCommand")
  suspend fun runCommand(request: CommandRequest, rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester, @AuthenticationPrincipal jwt: String): Flow<CommandResponse> {
...
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your Security Configuration?  I did change \@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<JwtAuthenticationToken> token to \@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<String> token and \@AuthenticationPrincipal String token neither worked.  I also added to the ConnectMapping that also did not work.

Comment: This one is hacked up for testing https://gist.github.com/yschimke/16a06e60e65b42f63d11db37d8f79d0c

Answer (score 0):

I am using Keycloak as jwt Issuer. Just follow up this [git repo](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-flights/tree/security). Only thing that didn't work for me is

```
@CurrentUserProfile Mono<UserProfile> currentUserProfile
```

Solution for that w.r.t above git repo will be using either of the below

```
@CurrentUserProfile Mono<Jwt> currentUserProfile
```

or directly use

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt currentUserProfile
```

Hope this will work for you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by adding dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and that's all. (for 04.10.23)

[Here a good article about RSocket Security](https://jskim1991.medium.com/rsocket-using-spring-boot-d6561918d979) - here you must to add own handler bean with `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`

But if you see the `RSocketSecurityAutoConfiguration` you found this:

```
    @Bean
    RSocketMessageHandlerCustomizer rSocketAuthenticationPrincipalMessageHandlerCustomizer() {
        return (messageHandler) -> {
            messageHandler.getArgumentResolverConfigurer().addCustomResolver(new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver[]{new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()});
        };
    }
```

So you don't need to overide this handler

PS. I tested on simple `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt`

```
@MessageMapping("stream")
public Flux<?> stream(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt){

    final String userId = jwt.getSubject();
    log.debug("Received stream by : {}", userId);

    return service.doJob(userId);
}
```